# VB6 Adodc Versus vb.net Adodc

Tags: vb.net, vb6, compatibility, ado, recordset

I am upgrading a lot of vb6 code to .net. In this code, there are a lot of adodc recordset wrappers and they are used everywhere. Rewriting is not an option nor is replacing them. There are 1000s. It seems that in vb6, when you call a adodc.refresh and the recordset is empty, it doesn't do anything. However, in vb.net, if the recordset is empty, it throws a bof, eof, or empty recordset error and bombs out. Any ideas how I can easily handle this or am I missing something? I could do a try catch for every one but it already has an error handling system that I would have to completely rewrite. Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you have to rewrite the error handling? Just add a layer around the innermost part of the code, just to catch the specific exception you get when you get a "bof, eof, or empty recordset error". Also, if you have a lot of duplication, then this might be a good time to get rid of the duplication. That way, you would only have to "rewrite" the error handling once, and not 1000 times. Invest in a copy of ReSharper, which despite its name, has good support for VB.NET.

Comment: The original code has on error goto label all over the place. I used a find replace to insert a special catch to resume next as you suggested. It worked. Ish. The problem is, once the adodc returns with a bof, eof, it sets the object to nothing. So any successive calls to the adodc object, it returns with an object not referenced error.  I guess if I could figure out how to create a new object in the error handler...?  ....Ugh.... I HATE the adodc.... Thanks though John.

Comment: Could you create an ADODC wrapper object which implements the ADODC interface, and delegates all methods/properties to the intern ADODC object, all except the Refresh method, which you treat specially?